# Catchall 301 rule to resolve voting URL strings back to assoicated pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, google-search-console

For whatever reason, Google is attempting to crawl URL strings associated with the voting feature on my site. Google finds errors and shows these in Webmaster Tools. I'd like to create a catch all 301 rule that resolve to the URL featuring the voting.

So these:

- http://bussongs.com/vote/dapplegray.php/1
- http://bussongs.com/vote/dapplegray.php/2
- http://bussongs.com/vote/dapplegray.php/3
- http://bussongs.com/vote/dapplegray.php/4
- http://bussongs.com/vote/dapplegray.php/5

(dapplegray.php represents the page name, 1-5 being the vote values).

..would resolve to:
http://bussongs.com/songs/dapplegray.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule as your first rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/vote/dapplegray\.php/ /songs/dapplegray.php
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava!


And as a catchall for songs on the site (ie. where dapplegray.php could be anything.php), it'd be something like this:
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/vote/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /songs/$1`

Comment: Yes that should work though I don't know all the details of those URLs. Let me know if you run into any problems.